# large, long images scrolling across screen at different speeds, and off of the left of the screen

Tags: android, scroll, horizontalscrollview

So I have multiple very long images (like 2000x100) that i want to have scrolling across the screen at different speeds.  and my original solution is not working out.  Originally, I placed them all in a HorizontalScrollView, and made a runnable that used setPadding to adjust the position of the ImageViews within the scrollView. This works, however, the background that is supposed to remain mostly stationary on the screen, shakes back and forth as you scroll, and lags behind the scroll location significantly. It's choppy and it looks bad.

Is there any other way that I can move images across the screen to achieve the desired effect?

(could I perhaps use a frame layout, and set an ontouchlistener? then how would you move the layout across the screen?)

I set up a layout so that the images protrude off of the right of the screen correctly, but I can't seem to move them off of the left of the screen (setpadding(-50,0,0,0) does not work)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using relative layouts within a frame layout.  I set an ontouchlistener for the frame layout and used the scrollTo method for each image with a modifying coefficient.  I had not previously noticed the scrollTo and scrollBy methods of the layout.